# Create class method alias without being registered as a properties

Tags: javascript, typescript, alias

I'm trying to create a method alias in a Class, this code works fine

```
class Foo {
    bar = "Hello World!";

    x() {
        console.log(this.bar);
    }

    y = this.x;
}

const foo = new Foo();
foo.y(); // prints out "Hello World"
```

However, the `y` becomes a property of `foo`, for example if I do

```js
console.log(foo);
```

It will shows

```
Foo { bar: 'Hello World!', y: [Function: x] } // I want y to be the method and not shown on the console.log like `x`, not property of foo
```

Is there any way to create method alias without it being registered as a property?

Comment: Method is just enumerable property. Maybe you are looking for static properties? It is not clear for me

Comment: I don't know what's the correct term for that, but as you can see when I do  `console.log(foo);`, it shows `y: [Function: x]` while `x()` is not. I want `y` to be hidden too just like `x`. Check my answer for example.

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to achieve this by doing so:

```
declare interface Foo {
    /**
     * Method alias for x();
     */
    y(): void
}

class Foo {
    bar = "Hello World!";

    x() {
        console.log(this.bar);
    }
}
Foo.prototype.y = Foo.prototype.x;


const foo = new Foo();
console.log(foo); // Foo { bar: 'Hello World!' }
foo.y(); // prints out "Hello World"
```

but I'm still accepting other answer for shorter / cleaner way

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `private` flag:

```js
class Foo {
    bar = "Hello World!";

    x() {
        console.log(this.bar);
    }

    #y = this.x;
}

const foo = new Foo(); // Foo {bar: "Hello World!"}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8BQ0PQEZgE7QF5oAiACQFMQQkB1eXEAEwEJiBuVdTADwAoBKFF0yZg8AHYR4IcgDpqAc14AXABYBLCLJy5%20HEQF9OIgMQBPQtDWbZ3DkdRjJy6ADNEl8eQDucRAI4gA)

Please keep in mind, it is a new feature, so it might not work on oldest browsers

Comment: This prevents access from outside as it's a "*hard privacy*", `Private fields can’t be accessed or even detected outside of the containing class - even by JS users! Sometimes we call this hard privacy.` from [Typescript 3.8 Release Notes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-8.html). So `new Foo().#y();` wont work. `Property '#y' is not accessible outside class 'Foo' because it has a private identifier`

Comment: Correct. I thought you  don't want to allow accessing this property.

Comment: I do, I just want it to not shows up on `console.log` just like `x()` method